# Serial downvoting, tried the flag method but nothing has happened

Tags: discussion

I believe I have been serial downvoted.

[image]

I waited first past midnight between april 20 and 21.
No serial downvotes was detected by the system, but as you can see from the image I was yet again possibly serial downvoted.
I waited another day and nothing happened.
So yesterday I did what all other threads say and flag on of the posts to mods and explaining the possible serial downvote.
It was `helpful`, but nothing happened.

[image]

So does that mean I have not been serial downvoted and all these downvotes are correct?

Comment: It means a mod agreed something doesn't look quite right and forwarded it to staff to review...

Comment: @JonClements Thanks, that explains it. I didn't see that beeing mentioned in any of the other threads.

Comment: @JonClements Of-coarse marking the flag as _helpful_ indicates as you said _look quite right and forwarded it to staff to review_. An additional comment e.g. _Sent for Review_ while marking _helpful_ may provide some affirmation and temporary relief to the concerned users.